# On closer examination

Tags: prepositions

> On closer examination, the investigators found out the blood type didn't match that of hers.

I would like to know what **on** means here.

I think it seems to mean either **on the basis of closer examination** or **during closer examination**.

And is it incorrect to use **in** instead of **on**? 
I think it's not incorrect though the intent of the sentence would be different from the original and suppose **in** could be used though not usually collocated and sounding so unidiomtaic that no one would write in this way below.

> In closer examination, the investigators found out the blood type didn't match that of hers, but not in normal examination.

I'm feeling that I need to add **but not in normal examination** in order to compare the counter-situations if I must use **in**.

Comment: *In* is incorrect.  You can think of *on X* as "on *the occasion of doing* X", so you can see how "in" doesn't make sense there.

Comment: @Stangton But I've found out quite a few sentences where it's used in books by googling.

Comment: On the occasion, in the event, at the time, with the circumstance or by the means -- it's very hard to explain why a native writer might prefer to see "closer examination" as an occasion rather than an event, time, circumstance or means.  My native-reader's eye sees "on closer examination" (and, pompously, "upon closer examination") as the natural choice, but, aside from noting frequency of occurrence, I'm at a loss to explain why.  "During closer examination" works in this context, although it sounds artificial or foreign.  Neither does "on the basis of" pass by my eye without a hitch.

Comment: @Gary Botnovcan I suspect it would be because of the **on**'s basic meaning of **contact** and a contextual reason.

Answer (score 1):

It is [Merriam-Webster's definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on) no 3: 
"—used as a function word to indicate a time frame during which something takes place"

With a present participle, it means "at the time of" or "just after". With a verb of perception or discovery (eg "on hearing", "on examining") it might also have a connotation of the result, but with other verbs (eg "on arriving") it doesn't usually.

A paraphrase here would be "having examined it more closely".

Comment: Isn't there any chance to interpret it to be **on the basis of** ? If not at all, is it because of the semantic influence on **on**, of **examination** ?  I suppose it could be right personally to think such words as **examination** and **inspection** would be so well fit with such a situation which necessarily has to take a sustained time in doing something, that it would be normal to mean **during**.

Comment: Where do you get this "during" from? I can't think of any context in which "on" means "during".

Answer (score 1):

Either of your meanings could be reasonable interpretations of "On closer examination", depending on the context (and neither would be far off, regardless).

Generally, this is dependent on the action taken. For example, in

> On closer examination, the investigators **determined** that she was innocent.

I would say that "on" is used for your first definition "on the basis of" [(see Merriam-Webster definition 7a)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on) .

However, in

> On closer examination, the investigators **saw** that the blood type of the sample didn't match hers.

I would say that "on" is used for your second definition "during" [(see Merriam-Webster definition 3)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on)

In answer to your question, I would say it depends on how "found out" is interpreted, as I have seen in used in both ways, as an interoperation of data and observation of data, respectively.

It is not idiomatically correct to say "in closer examination" (although I have once seen the word used once for "errors in the closer examination", which is similar but refers to "examination" as a set of procedures and actions rather than a process of observation).

Speaking of alternatives, I have seen "during closer examination" and "after closer examination" used used with your second definition.

I have also seen "under closer examination" used occasionally, but in such a case, it is the object of examination that then acts as the subject, as in

> On closer examination, the blood sample taken from the crime scene did not match the suspect's blood type.

Comment: I suppose the meaning of **during** of **on** should have originated from its basic meaning of **contact**. Continuously acting of a subject could be expressed with **on** because of the semantic reason as in **on a walk, on a journey, on a ride, on vacation, on a binge, on offer, on demand, or etc..**